# camel wmq transactions - ack mode as TRANSACTED

Tags: transactions, apache-camel, ibm-mq

Please find the below scenarios or camel route

```
from("wmq:queue:eventQueue + "?useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true") 
    .transacted() 
    .bean(orchestrator, "processMessage(${body}, ${headers})");
```

and for transaction i am maintaining JmsTransactionManager. please find the same. actually i have gone through Chapter 9 in the Camel in Action book. based on that I configured txn.

```
<bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="transacted" value="true" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
</bean>
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="wmqConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now in Chapter 9 in the Camel in Action book, author mentioned about ACTIVEMQ.DLQ, but what will happen in case of Websphere MQ. 
My requirement is if at all processMessage(${body}, ${headers}) fails to process and throws exception , camel should not acknowledge and message should be there as it is inside WMQ.

Could you please help me for the same.

Thanks 
Satyajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have transacted JMS, I assume by

> camel should not acknowledge

you want the transaction to roll back and not commit.

It's very problematic to simply roll back to WMQ "as it is". If you won't take precaution, Camel will find the message again and try to reprocess it. The second attempt will very likely fail again and the process repeats. The logs will fill up very quickly.

You should specifiy the "BONAME" and "BOTRESH" properties on the WMQ queue and have the rolled back message to a dead letter queue after a few retries. I think the default WMQ DLQ is `SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE`.